# Error when trying to call variables from another py file in the same directory

Tags: python

I am trying to use the Google Sheets API to pull information from a sheet then convert it into a string of the values separated by commas, I then want to pass it to a file that sends a text message containing that information. My current problem is that when I try to call the variable containing the string I get an error saying AttributeError: module 'sheetsReader' has no attribute 'result_string'. This is my first time trying to use different objects in python so I am a bit confused, I am unsure if I need to define classes to call them correctly like in java or if I am just missing something.

here is my code for both files.

```
import os
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
value = []

global result_string
def main():
    
    credentials = None
    if os.path.exists("tocken.json"):
        credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES)
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open("token.json","w") as token:
            token.write(credentials.to_json())
    try:
        service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)
        sheets = service.spreadsheets()
        
        result = sheets.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range="Sheet1!A1:A9").execute()
        
        values = result.get("values", [])
        
        for row in values:
            value.append(row)
            
        result_string = ', '.join([inner_list[0] for inner_list in value])
    
    
    except HttpError as error:
        print(error)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
from datetime import time, timedelta, datetime
import Alert
import time as tm
import sheetsReader

text = sheetsReader.result_string



def job():
    Alert.email_alert("todo","stop", "4807931338@vtext.com")
    
    
    
schedule.every().day("7:20").do(job)




while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    tm.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I think you should import the var before you use it

Comment: No value is ever assigned to `result_string` in the first file.  The only reference to it is inside `main()`, which isn't called when the file is imported (due to the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block); even if it was called, it assigns a local variable that cannot be seen anywhere else.  The `global` statement would have to be *inside* the function to be meaningful - or better yet, `return` the value from the function.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're encountering is related to how you're trying to access the '**result_string**' variable from the '*sheetsReader*' module. The error message "**AttributeError: module 'sheetsReader' has no attribute 'result_string'**" suggests that Python doesn't recognize '**result_string**' as an attribute of the '**sheetsReader**' module.

*In Python, to access variables from one module in another module, you need to import them correctly.*

*In the '**sheetsReader.py**' file, modify the variable declaration to make it global*:

```
result_string = ''

def main():
    # Your existing code to populate result_string
```

*In the '**main.py**' file, import the '**sheetsReader**' module and access the '**result_string**' variable as follows*:

```
import sheetsReader

text = sheetsReader.result_string

# Rest of your code...
```

*Make sure both the '**sheetsReader.py**' and '**main.py**' files are in the same directory.*

With these changes, you should be able to access the '**result_string**' variable from the sheetsReader module in your '**main.py**' file without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `global` statement declares that a variable is not to be created as  a new local object, but it should be interpreted as a global and its value inherited from an enclosing block or module. The `global` statement should not be used when a variable is defined, and is never necessary outside of a class or function definition.

In your module, you declare result_string as global, but it has not been DEFINED (does not have a value) at the time the module is imported. You can easily fix this by replacing the `global` statement with a simple

```
result_string = ''
```

at the top of your module. This is the correct way to define a variable that will be imported by other modules.